# Javascript close createElement('iframe')

Tags: javascript, dom

I am creating an iframe from a bookmarklet and then appending with HTML inside to show the page content.

I am having trouble closing the iframe.

A user clicks on the bookmarklet when viewing other web pages.

I can post to the original URL with target="_parent" the iframe was opened over but this is problematic as some sites don't allow URLs to be posted, plus it means a double back button operation of the user to get where they were before they clicked the bookmarklet.

This is the bookmarklet code: (it works for testing)

```
javascript:(function(d){
  var%20modal=document.createElement('iframe');
  modal.setAttribute('src','http://9ammusic.com/test/bm2.html?url='+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href)+
  '&page_title='+document.title);
  modal.setAttribute('scrolling','no');
  modal.setAttribute('name','my_modal');
  modal.className='modal';
  document.body.appendChild(modal);

  var%20c=document.createElement('link');
  c.type='text/css';
  c.rel='stylesheet';
  c.href='//9ammusic.com/css/iframe.css';
  document.body.appendChild(c);
}(document));
```

At the moment I am closing the frame using the URL i am getting from `window.location.href` like so:

```
<form method=post action=<?=$_GET['url']?> target="_parent">
```

But this is not ideal at all - is there a way to just directly close the iframe without affecting the parent window at all?

Comment: How are you closing the iframe?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I have amended the question to show the info

Comment: Uh, you're reloading the main page in order to clear the iframe? That's just not right... The iframe (i.e. the page loaded into the iframe) should have a button, that removes the iframe on-click...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I know - But I don't know how to do it, that's the question